# NodeJS how to handle nested try/catch mechanism

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to code two nested try/catch and put retry logic for it. So when inner try/catch catches error I want it to send to outer catch and inside of it I will increase retry count by 1. So when it comes to 5 I will return from while loop. But my problem is that when inner try/catch throws an exception it is not caught by outer one. How can I make sure that it catches the error?

```
    try {
      channel.assertQueue(name, { durable: true, arguments: { "x-queue-type": "quorum" } }, async (error, queue) => {
        if (error)
          throw error;

        if (queue) {
          try {
            channel.sendToQueue(name, Buffer.from(message));
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      //retry count will be increased.
      throw e.message;
    }
```

Comment: Because your inner throw is for the function which is defined inside assertQueue. To catch it outside, you need to throw it outside the body of assertQueue.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your response so you're saying inner try/catch is not needed? I have also tried that but still outer one can't catch error if sendToQueue throws an exception

Comment: i don't think you need to use multiple try catch, I always use only one try catch and it works perfectly

Comment: I think this doesn't work because when sendToQueue throws an error since it's inside of async promise outer try/catch can't catch it. It's definitely not working in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a callback to `channel.assertQueue`, and not an `async` one for certain, instead you should [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) it. With `await`, you can then catch the errors in the outer `try`/`catch`.

You're probably looking for

```
async function attemptToSendMessage() {
  for (let retryCount = 0; retryCount < 5; retryCount++) {
    try {
      const queue = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        channel.assertQueue(
          name,
          { durable: true, arguments: { "x-queue-type": "quorum" } },
          (error, queue) => {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else resolve(queue);
          }
        );
      });
      if (queue) {
        await channel.sendToQueue(name, Buffer.from(message));
      }
      return; // Exit the loop if the message is sent successfully
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("Failed to send message after 5 attempts.");
}
```

However, assuming you are using [this API](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#channel_assertQueue), you don't even need to promisify the `assertQueue` function yourself - it already returns a promise if you don't pass a callback. So simplify further to

```
async function attemptToSendMessage() {
  for (let retryCount = 0; retryCount < 5; retryCount++) {
    try {
      const queue = await channel.assertQueue(
        name,
        { durable: true, arguments: { "x-queue-type": "quorum" } },
      );
      if (queue) {
        await channel.sendToQueue(name, Buffer.from(message));
      }
      return; // Exit the loop if the message is sent successfully
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("Failed to send message after 5 attempts.");
}
```

Comment: This code also worked for me, thank you so much but what's the difference between  two codes :) I have tested the case where sendToQueue fails and both codes worked like I want it

Comment: It's more straightforward, doesn't require to explicitly `reject()` on errors from `sendToQueue`, and will still work when `if (queue)` does not match

Comment: Yes, I'm using this API but queue value which is returning in both of the codes are different. First oen returns sth like this : 
{
  queue: 'foobar',
  messageCount: 0,
  consumerCount: 0
}
But second one is extremely detailed response.

Comment: I really appreciate your support btw, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the outer catch block catches the error thrown in the inner try/catch block, you can modify your code as follows:

```
let retryCount = 0;

async function attemptToSendMessage() {
  while (retryCount < 5) {
    try {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        channel.assertQueue(
          name,
          { durable: true, arguments: { "x-queue-type": "quorum" } },
          async (error, queue) => {
            if (error) {
              reject(error); // Reject the promise if an error occurs
              return;
            }

            if (queue) {
              try {
                channel.sendToQueue(name, Buffer.from(message));
                resolve(); // Resolve the promise if the message is sent successfully
              } catch (e) {
                reject(e); // Reject the promise if an error occurs while sending the message
              }
            }
          }
        );
      });
      break; // Exit the while loop if the message is sent successfully
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      retryCount++; // Increase the retry count
    }
  }

  if (retryCount === 5) {
    throw new Error("Failed to send message after 5 attempts.");
  }
}

// Usage
try {
  await attemptToSendMessage();
} catch (e) {
  // Handle the error here
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this actually works exactly how I want it! Great work!

Comment: I have one question, why we need return when error is occurred ? It's the first if case inside of async method

Comment: This will hang when `if (queue)` is falsy. Better write it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76228075/1048572).

Comment: I have tested this code when sendToQueue throws exception and it works fine